# cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'wsdl:definitions' cannot have character, because the type's content type is element-only. when the xml is validated

Tags: xml, eclipse, wsdl

I have a very large (>2800 lines) wsdl file that is throwing the following error...

```
cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'wsdl:definitions' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

I have scanned the full 2800+ lines looking for missing or extra tags, mislpaced comments, etc.

I have used the XML validation services online and all say valid XML.

I have used a stand alone XML editor and it says the XML is well formed.

The eclipse editor is the only place that throws that error.  At 2800 lines I hesitate to put it here.  But if someone thinks that is needed I will.

Comment: "throws that error" means what exactly? Which release of Eclipse and which editor in Eclipse is this? Is it also shown in the Problems View?

Comment: In eclipse Version: 2.3.500.v20210303-1800 Build id: I20210303-1800 the wsdl file has an error tag on the definitions element...cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'wsdl:definitions' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Answer (score 1):

Actually 2800 lines is rather small, as XML files go. But admittedly, it's large enough that finding this kind of problem by eye is difficult.

I'd suggest exploring the file with an interactive XPath tool, e.g. xmlstarlet, Saxon's Gizmo, or the XPath search tool in an IDE such as Oxygen. Start by searching for `//wsdl:definitions[text()[normalize-space()]]`.  If there really is a `wsdl:definitions` with character content, this should find it.